# SQL Join tables to convert id to username

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have one **users** table with :

```
| username | user_id |
```

and a **friends** table with:

```
| user_id | friend_id |
```

I POST the `user_id` to retrieve the friends of a certain user.

I am using `$query = "SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = ?"`
I also want the username of these friends , so I am trying to JOIN the tables.

```
$query = 'SELECT f.friend_id,u.username FROM friends f WHERE f.user_id = ? JOIN users u ON u.user_id = f.friend_id'
```

but the result is nil in this case. is my logic wrong ?

Comment: Put `WHERE` clause after the join condition `ON`.

Comment: Please check the documentation on how to get error information. There is an obvious syntax error in your query, but you can't really come here and ask every time. If you get the error message, you can debug your queries much easier and quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Update your MYSQL query:

```
$query = 'SELECT f.friend_id,u.username FROM friends f WHERE f.user_id = ? JOIN users u ON u.user_id = f.friend_id'
```

with this query :

```
$query = 'SELECT f.friend_id, u.username FROM friends f JOIN users u ON u.user_id = f.friend_id WHERE f.user_id = ?'
```

Wherever we use MYSQL **JOIN** ... **ON** in table put this before any conditional clause like **WHERE**.

Comment: Congratulations, the only answer that is not only right, but also provides at least some explanation of the cause of the issue.

Comment: Really nice answer, it is helpful to me!

Answer (score 0):

your query should be this

```
SELECT f.friend_id,u.username FROM friends f JOIN users u ON u.user_id = f.user_id WHERE f.user_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'SELECT f.friend_id, u.username FROM friends f JOIN users u ON u.user_id = f.friend_id where f.user_id = ?'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "select f.`friend_id`, u.`username` 
          from `users` u 
          join `friends` f on u.user_id = f.user_id
          join `users` u2 on u2.user_id = f.user_id
          where u2.`user_id` = ?"
```

Comment: I'm just reviewing answers, but what is this answering? Code looks fine, but it would really help, not only OP of Q, but also people who google and hit a hashlink to your answer, it would really help if you added more substance and told readers, as well as OP, why you recomend this answer and what it does that's different from original question issue.

Answer (score -1):

Someything like this ought to work

```
$query = "select f.`friend_id`, u.`username` from `friends` f
          left outer join `users` u on u.`user_id`=f.`friend_id` 
          where f.`user_id` = ?";
```

didn't spot initial errors...

Answer (score -1):

it should be

```
$query = 'SELECT f.friend_id,u.username FROM friends f WHERE f.user_id = ? ANd u.user_id = f.user_id'
```

Comment: Ah, yes it will probably work. I misread the query and overlooked the fact that you replaced the normal `join` that OP uses by the old fashioned comma-based joins that were replaced in 1992 by the 'new' standard. That, and the fact that there is no explanation whatsoever, caused me to feel this answer is not useful.

Comment: you made it not useful that's why :)